# Expo App Crashing when open @react-native-community/datetimepicker

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

Hi I am building an Expo app and want to allow my users to pick a date and time.

I installed [the React Native DateTimePicker library](https://github.com/react-native-datetimepicker/datetimepicker) and implemented a basic RNDDateTimePicker component as directed in the Github. However, whenever I click on the TimePicker component, my app just crashes without logging any errors. My basic component is shown below. Does anyone know what the problem with this could be? Thank you.

```
 <RNDateTimePicker mode={'time'} value={startTime} onChange={(event, time) => { setStartTime(time) }}  />
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you check the start time. It should be new Date()

Comment: Hi, I do have it as new Date() and the crash still occurs

Comment: Can you try checking the logs in android studio or xcode and provide more clarification

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue. Then I used "react-native-modal-datetime-picker" library. It worked for me.